# Script to restore database for last x number of days

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I work with an app that doesn't log as much stuff as I would like it to and often find myself having to restore earlier versions of the database to determine when various anomalies occurred in order to isolate what may have caused the issue at hand.

I'd like a script that I can just plug in a database name and run it so that it will restore the database to a specified time for each of the last specified number of days.

So basically I envision having 3 variables like so:

```
declare @DbName varchar(100) = 'DbName'
declare @StartTime datetime = '20130902 5:45pm'
declare @NumDays int = 12
```

And then the script would restore DbName to the following databases:

```
'DbName 20130902'
'DbName 20130903'
etc...
'DbName 20130913'
```

I don't care whether the time is appended or not so long as the date is there.  I'm pretty good with sql statements in general, but I don't do a lot of procedural t-sql programming so I'm not quite sure the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: This sounds more like a request for code than a question, re-word it possibly? Show us what you've done to implement your idea.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Okay, I'll rework the question a bit...